# $.post() behaves different than $.ajax( same paramenters )

Tags: json, jquery, firefox4

I came across something weird, that I want to expose and know if someone as an explanation for it.

Some time back i had a simple post:

```
$.post("/Route/Save", { myObj: JSON.stringify(myObj), accessToken: getAccessToken()}, function(data)
{
    //do stuff
});
```

and it was working nicely, now doesn't work, and only the accessToken paramenter is correctly received in the route controller

I changed it to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Route/Save",
    data: '{ myObj:' +  JSON.stringify(myObj) + ',accessToken:"' + getAccessToken()+'"}',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'JSON',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

And now it works. I'm using firefox 4 and IE9 and believe the reason is connected to the way the browser is sending the info encoded... in the $.post() case it looks like it sends the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I'll be glad to hear from you guys!

Regards,
byte_slave

Comment: change `datatype='JSON'` into `dataType='json'`

Comment: @diEcho - $.ajax() works fine as it is, it's just its jquery shorthand $.post() that doesn't behave like before!

Comment: "it doesn't work" is utterly useless. What debugging steps have you performed? Where does the `myObj` parameter vanish in the call stack?

Comment: I'm using asp.net mvc and inside the /Route/Save i can see that the parameter "myObj" is null with $.post() and has value with $.ajax().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it was working before; perhaps a jQuery update changed behaviour?

As to your question on the content-type, $.post is a shorthand wrapper around $.ajax, and from the [$.ajax api page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the default value for the contentType is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

AFAIK, you can't specify the contentType using $.post(). I could be wrong though.

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent with $.ajax should be

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Route/Save",
    data: { myObj: JSON.stringify(myObj), accessToken: getAccessToken()},
    type: 'POST',       
    success: function (data)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: -1 For not reading my question correctly! The $.ajax() method is working.... is the shorthand $.post() that doesn't like before it did!